# backupbuddy - strange fonts after migration

Tags: fonts

After migrating a site with BackupBuddy , the fonts/icons used from Icomoon + WashIcons + FontAwesome + Custom Fonts are displayed as squares or strange chars.
For example this one is displayed as a square:

```
<i class="fa-facebook"></i>
```

Any idea why this is happening?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I've found the solution here: http://ce3wiki.theturninggate.net/doku.php?id=cross-domain_issues_broken_web_fonts